# Jenkins Appium job getting terminated while finding xpath

Tags: jenkins, automation, appium-android

I am facing below issue on jenkins, job getting terminated once appium driver start finding xpath.
Same code is working fine in local script execution in my system.

Appium Logs:

```
[debug] [W3C (fb32b0a7)] Calling AppiumDriver.getWindowRect() with args: ["fb32b0a7-cca3-48cd-97e1-4e42fb0b9ea8"]
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/window/current/size' to command name 'getWindowSize'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /window/current/size] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/c07ca9f1-c603-4ce8-a589-6d44b8935f58/window/current/size] with body: {}
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"c07ca9f1-c603-4ce8-a589-6d44b8935f58","value":{"height":2560,"width":1440}}
[debug] [W3C (fb32b0a7)] Responding to client with driver.getWindowRect() result: {"width":1440,"height":2560,"x":0,"y":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/fb32b0a7-cca3-48cd-97e1-4e42fb0b9ea8/window/rect 200 41 ms - 50
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/fb32b0a7-cca3-48cd-97e1-4e42fb0b9ea8/touch/perform
[HTTP] {"actions":[{"action":"press","options":{"x":1008,"y":1792}},{"action":"wait","options":{"ms":2000}},{"action":"moveTo","options":{"x":1,"y":1792}},{"action":"release","options":{}}]}
[debug] [W3C (fb32b0a7)] Calling AppiumDriver.performTouch() with args: [[{"action":"press","options":{"x":1008,"y":1792}},{"action":"wait","options":{"ms":2000}},{"action":"moveTo","options":{"x":1,"y":1792}},{"action":"release","options":{}}],"fb32b0a7-cca3-48cd-97e1-4e42fb0b9ea8"]
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/touch/perform' to command name 'performTouch'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /touch/perform] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/c07ca9f1-c603-4ce8-a589-6d44b8935f58/touch/perform] with body: {"startX":1008,"startY":1792,"endX":1,"endY":1792,"steps":56}
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"c07ca9f1-c603-4ce8-a589-6d44b8935f58","value":null}
[debug] [W3C (fb32b0a7)] Responding to client with driver.performTouch() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/fb32b0a7-cca3-48cd-97e1-4e42fb0b9ea8/touch/perform 200 2940 ms - 14
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status
[HTTP] {}
[debug] [GENERIC] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[debug] [GENERIC] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.16.0"}}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1 ms - 68
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/fb32b0a7-cca3-48cd-97e1-4e42fb0b9ea8/element
[HTTP] {"using":"xpath","value":"//*[contains(@text,'Not Now')]"}
[debug] [W3C (fb32b0a7)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["xpath","//*[contains(@text,'Not Now')]","fb32b0a7-cca3-48cd-97e1-4e42fb0b9ea8"]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/c07ca9f1-c603-4ce8-a589-6d44b8935f58/element] with body: {"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@text,'Not Now')]","context":"","multiple":false}
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"c07ca9f1-c603-4ce8-a589-6d44b8935f58","value":{"ELEMENT":"d9a20579-ec83-44c3-b25b-303103eea1e0","element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"d9a20579-ec83-44c3-b25b-303103eea1e0"}}
[debug] [W3C (fb32b0a7)] Responding to client with driver.findElement() result: {"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"d9a20579-ec83-44c3-b25b-303103eea1e0","ELEMENT":"d9a20579-ec83-44c3-b25b-303103eea1e0"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/fb32b0a7-cca3-48cd-97e1-4e42fb0b9ea8/element 200 233 ms - 137
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/fb32b0a7-cca3-48cd-97e1-4e42fb0b9ea8
[HTTP] {}
[debug] [W3C (fb32b0a7)] Calling AppiumDriver.deleteSession() with args: ["fb32b0a7-cca3-48cd-97e1-4e42fb0b9ea8"]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'quitSessionRequested' logged at 1583220093867 (12:51:33 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[Appium] Removing session fb32b0a7-cca3-48cd-97e1-4e42fb0b9ea8 from our master session list
[debug] [UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 session
[debug] [UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 server session
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/' to command name 'deleteSession'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [DELETE /] to [DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/c07ca9f1-c603-4ce8-a589-6d44b8935f58] with no body
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"c07ca9f1-c603-4ce8-a589-6d44b8935f58","value":null}
```

Comment: Can anybody update on this.

Comment: Could you please leave here the block or snippet of your test code here?

Comment: This issue has been resolved, updated dependency version of Java-client and selenium-remote-driver.